# Strange error when I want to deploy community to scratch org. Is it sfdx bug or I missing something?

Tags: community, deployment, error, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

When I trying to deploy community to my scratch org I receive following error.
Template that I use is `Build Your Own` and has route service-not-available by default.

```
    Error  force-app/main/default/experiences/MySites1.site-meta.xml 
    The service-not-available route in MySites1/routes/serviceNotAvailable.json 
    isn’t supported for this template in API version 52.0. 
    Either remove the route file and its corresponding view file or update 
    the API version.
```

I wonder is it some known bug or I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_sna_page.htm&type=5&release=232) use the below

If you’re using the Service Not Available page in a scratch org, add PublishExpBuilderBasedSna and PublishAuraExpBuilderBasedSna features to your scratch org configuration.

```
"features": ["PublishExpBuilderBasedSna", "PublishAuraExpBuilderBasedSna"]
```